# Estoy intentando configurar Apache como proxy inverso para un proyecto de java que corre con GlassFish

Tags: apache, glassfish, proxy

En el httpd.config de apache estoy poniendo esta configuracion
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName localhost

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8060/rd/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8060/rd/
```

#Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload"

```
ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
CustomLog "logs/access.log" common
```

al correr el proyecto de java levanta el glassfish en el puerto 8060 y me muestra el proyecto pero cuando intento ingresar al localhost de apache solo me carga el encabezado de la pagina y lo demas esta en blanco, al entrar a inspeccionar y consola me arroja que no detecta los js, css.                                                                    ocupo glashsfish 5 y apache httpd 2.4.58